# formatting the float for series float datatype

Tags: python, pandas

when trying below code  get the error **unsupported format string passed to Series.**float****
How to solve this problem

Code tried:

```
df['a3'] = "the value is {:.2f}".format(df['a2'])
```

Here ,
`df['a2'] consists of values [0.0,1.0,2.0] and its dtype is float64.`

How do i rectify this format error, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `str.format` like that. Instead, you can use `apply()` to do this for every item in the `a2` column:

```
df['a3'] = df['a2'].apply(lambda x: "the value is {:.2f}".format(x))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    a2                 a3
0  0.0  the value is 0.00
1  0.1  the value is 0.10
2  0.2  the value is 0.20
```

Bonus: Now, a trick, which might work for you (but might not) and which might be a bit faster would be to to do something like this:

```
df['a4'] = 'the value is ' + df['a2'].astype(str) + '!!'
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    a2                 a3                  a4
0  0.0  the value is 0.00  the value is 0.0!!
1  0.1  the value is 0.10  the value is 0.1!!
2  0.2  the value is 0.20  the value is 0.2!!
```